# Spring data jpa which is best to use for persisting or loading entities and having complex queries to load the entities

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jooq, querydsl

I see that there are different ways to load or save entities. I am comfortable with having creating proper entity graphs and avoid writing queries by leveraging JPA Specification. I am curious to know what is more convenient that is suitable for any use case (RDBMS).

- Jpa repositories
- JPQL/HQL/Native Queries using @Queries
- Derived methods
- Named Queries
- Specification in spring data jpa
- Query by Example.
- QueryDSL
- JOOQ (hot and trending topic)